# Architecture component - List to detail and back

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have a list with entries and I want to be able to navigate to the detail of an entry and back and keep the data of the list. The list shall keep all the items that it had before and maybe even the scroll position.

I am using the navigation architecture component. For this I have 3 Fragments: Search - Result - Detail. I have one navigation graph `navigation` that is used in the single activity for this app `NavigationActivity`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.features.NavigationActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've setup all actions and calling them like so:

```
val action = SearchResultFragmentDirections.actionSearchResultFragmentToDetailFragment(item)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

I tried to use the `popTo` in the navigaion graph but that did not change a thing. Does somebody know a solution to keep the states of the fragments with this scenario? Do I need another navigation graph?

//Edit:

I populate my list in a viewModel call in `onCreate`. This gets only called once in my flow, so the fragment is not destroyed. I can save the list items I retrieve in a local variable inside the fragment and repopulate my list by that in `onResume`, but this does not seem like the correct way.

Comment: Can you show us ViewModel initialization code and the call to `observe`?